# JSch SFTP file download

Tags: java, get, sftp, jsch

I am trying to download a file from SFTP server to my local machine using JSch. It only downloads 16371 bytes of data regardless of the file size and ends the transfer. It does not throw any exception. If the file is smaller than 16371 bytes it is transfered sucesfully, but for any larger file the transfer results in a corrupted file.

Comment: I think you are gonna need to show some code here...

Comment: I just instantiated the ChannelSftp object and called the get method. It works fine with smaller files, but stops after it transfered 16371 bytes.

Comment: can you turn up the log level on the JSch object and see if something jumps out?

Comment: Thank for your advice. I tried that and these are the last lines of JSch log:
  Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
  Disconnecting from ***.***.***.*** port 22
  Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to socket closed

Comment: looks like the server is disconnecting you.  Try tuning up the logs on your sshd server side and see what that has to say...

Comment: This would be the expected behavior if your progress monitor implementation's count() method returned false. Without seeing your code, it's hard to say, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I managed to solve this problem. I replaced:

```
    SftpProgressMonitor monitor = new MySftpProgressMonitor();
    channelSftp.get(sourceFile, destFile, monitor);
```

with:

```
    channelSftp.get(sourceFile, destFile);
```

After removing the progress monitor the transfer was sucesfull. I guess it is a bug inside Jsch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a special sftp server. My unique solution was use [LFTP](http://lftp.yar.ru/), wich is a linux command for automatize SFTP tasks. If you have a Linux environment it is very useful.

Example in PHP:
    $command = set net:timeout 30; lcd $directorioDestino; cd /Usr/companies/cdrusr357901/CallCenterRecords/; mget {$prefijoArchivosAuris}*; bye
    lftp -u {$this->user},{$this->password} -e '$command' sftp://{$this->host}